# Rails localization with SEO requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible always to have `http://sitename/en/some_url` for english version and `http://sitename/some_url` for ukrainian

Default rails behavior: store `locale` in session, that is why I can get english or ukrainian version on same url http://sitename/some_url depend on `locale` variable value. It's not SEO friendly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the info you need can be found here:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

For a nice, easy to follow tutorial on setting up locales, see:

https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/rails-i18n-guide/